# Swamy-Arora estimation of variance component in panel data

Tags: estimation, panel-data, stata, clustered-standard-errors

I wonder under which conditions the Swamy-Arora estimation is preferred over the conventional estimation method or the Wallace and Hussain estimator?

I'm running an unbalanced panel dataset with over 500 firms and only 1800 observations. I read that normally the Swamy-Arora estimation (name in Stata, in R it seems to be called Swamy-Arora transformation) is suitable for small samples. Now my sample is not small but my groups are very small (I am clustering standard errors around the firms).

When I use the swar estimation my confidence intervals are smaller and the coefficients of my explanatory variables are larger in absolute terms, giving me the results I expect in Stata, while without the swar estimation the results are less significant.

Any ideas?

My stata code is

```
xtreg y X, cluster(firm_id) robust sa /* sa = Swamy-Arora */
```

Comment: What is the "conventional" estimation method in this case? Imho, Swamy-Arora is the default method in most statistical packages.

Comment: Hi, so it seems to be. In stata, the only info I find is that the default is the "GLS random-effects estimator" and the alternative is the small sample Swamy-Arora estimator individual-level variance component (see Baltagi, 2008). With the addition of cluster(firm_id) the default seems to be the Huber/White/sandwich VCE estimator (see Wooldridge, 2009). As said my sample is about 1,700 so sure not that small but my individual groups average 3.1 so they are very small...

Comment: `cluster(firm_id)` in Stata is about the standard errors, not about the estimation of coefficients. If you are interested in how the various estimation methods compare, search for Monte Carlo simulations about the methods you are interested in.